# Read data from form in custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to get data from form in custom hook? I want to call `useSearch` hook in `SearchProducts` component and pass the submitted data. Is there any better solution for this?

```
function useSearch() {
  const submitHandle = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = [];

    const elements = event.target.childNodes;

    elements.forEach((element) => {
      data[element.name] = element.value;
      element.value = "";
    });


    // I need data from form here.
    console.log(data);
  };

  return {
    onSubmit: submitHandle,
  };
}
```

```
export default function SearchProducts() {
  const search = useSearch();

  return (
    <Container>
      <Form {...search}>
        <Input name="searchInput" />
        <SearchButton type="submit">search</SearchButton>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

```
export default function Input({ type, name }) {
  const input = useInput("");
  return <InputField type={type} name={name} {...input} />;
}
```

```
function useInput(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (value === false) {
      setValue(true);
    }
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return {
    value: value,
    onChange: handleChange,
  };
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the code you've shared?

Comment: @Drew Yes, in `useSearch `, I get all elements of form (inputs and button), but I need just input value.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking more if there was an issue/problem with the code and you need to debug/fix something, or if you were simply asking for a code review of working code, and were looking for "any better solution for this". If the code isn't working then please explain in better detail what isn't working, and include any errors and code stacktraces if they exist, and what the expected vs actual behavior is.